# Android Push Notification with FCM

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, android-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

Here are my cases for notification:
When Notification arrive, App might be Foreground, Background, or Closed

**1. For Foreground:**
When user tap on notification, app should show Main activity.

**2. For Background:**
When user tap on notification, App should bring to front and should show Main activity

**3. When App is closed:**
When user tap on notification, App should open, and should show Main Activity.

When I set intent with `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` & PendingIntent with `PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT`. It works as expected, but when user tap on notification, it do not call onCreate method of Main Activity.

```
private void showNotification() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DashboardActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(AppConstants.SCREEN, screen);
        intent.putExtra(AppConstants.USER_ID, user_id);
        intent.putExtra(AppConstants.TABLE_ID, table_id);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(getNotificationIcon())
            .setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentText(message)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
```

If you consider Above code then it needs to be executed a method from `MainActivity(DashboardActivity)` when user tap on notification.

Notes: When App is Foreground/Background, it should not close and open new. It must be update in existing app.

Hope you understand my situation. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When User tap on a notification which have intent with `"Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP"`, will not call onCreate method of the intent. it will call a method when user tap on notification, which is written below:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {}
```

Thanks for reading this question :)